# "Field 'name' doesn't have a default value" when `name` is explicitly being provided

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm having a very strange error. The extra weird thing is that it only happens on the development host, but not locally, despite that both are running the exact same code. The only difference is what database they're writing to, but I can insert just fine at the mysql console.

If I try the following query at the Rails console:

`Category.create!(:name => "FOOBAR", :parent_id => 141)`

I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Field 'name' doesn't have a default value: 
INSERT INTO `taxons` (`type`, `parent_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Category', 
141, '2020-02-05 18:48:54', '2020-02-05 18:48:54')
```

I'm literally providing the value for name, so I don't understand why it's not using it when it tries to create and validate the new record.

ETA: It's definitely a database issue, because if I run the local code with the development database, I get the same error. I can't directly make changes to the database (i.e. I have to ask the devops team to do it), but I guess the real question is about what needs to change there for this to work? The difference between the two databases is that locally, it allows for `name` to have `DEFAULT NULL`, and on development, it's `NOT NULL`, but why should this be necessary, if I'm always supplying a value for `name`?

Answer (score 0):

I edited database.yml to specify `strict: false`. Problem solved.